# wordpress ajax autocompleter search box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

i wanna create a search box with ajax that show instant post titles but i couldnt find useful things on internet can some one help ?

i know i must use this for get result in wpdb

```
$words = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT concat( post_title, '|', 1 ) name, 1 cnt, ID FROM ".$wpdb-  >prefix."posts t 
WHERE post_status='publish' and (post_type='post') and post_date < NOW() and post_title LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY post_title");
```

but i dont know about ajax and dont know where should i put 
anyone can help me?

Comment: i just made one of these, it uses a plugin that creates a JSON endpoint for your posts, I pull that in with javascript on load and write a script to look through that JSON object on keyup. It's super fast and only requires you to make one ajax call on load.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not opposed to using a WordPress Plugin to complete the task, I'd recommend checking out the [SearchAutocomplete](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-autocomplete/) plugin in the WordPress.org repo. It using jQuery UI and you can create custom themes using the [jQuery UI Theme Roller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).

With the SearchAutocomplete WordPress plugin you can set the search box to just posts or a combination or posts, pages and media as well as categories, tags and [insert post format] (i.e. it supports custom post types & taxonomies).

This would be the "easy" route and the route that would get you up and running the quickest. Of course, a custom solution will provide you with finer grain control. It all depends on what you need beyond the ability to populate the search box.